# Returning a particular index of a list based on another index of the same list R

Tags: r, list, function, indexing, lapply

I have a list like below(This is just one element of a list there are 50 more for every state)

```
$AK
                                       Hospital.Name State   HeartAttack  HeartFailure     Pneumonia
99                  PROVIDENCE ALASKA MEDICAL CENTER    AK          13.4          12.4           7.9
103                         ALASKA REGIONAL HOSPITAL    AK          14.5          13.4           8.9
102                      FAIRBANKS MEMORIAL HOSPITAL    AK          15.5          15.6           9.8
106                     ALASKA NATIVE MEDICAL CENTER    AK          15.7          11.6          11.6
100                   MAT-SU REGIONAL MEDICAL CENTER    AK          17.7          11.4           9.0
104               YUKON KUSKOKWIM DELTA REG HOSPITAL    AK Not Available          11.2           6.9
110                         SITKA COMMUNITY HOSPITAL    AK Not Available Not Available           7.8
114 PEACEHEALTH KETCHIKAN MEDICAL             CENTER    AK Not Available          11.4           8.0
101                       BARTLETT REGIONAL HOSPITAL    AK Not Available          11.6           8.1
113                   NORTON SOUND REGIONAL HOSPITAL    AK Not Available Not Available           8.1
111             PROVIDENCE KODIAK ISLAND MEDICAL CTR    AK Not Available Not Available           8.2
115                         SOUTH PENINSULA HOSPITAL    AK Not Available          10.8           8.5
107                            MT EDGECUMBE HOSPITAL    AK Not Available Not Available           9.6
105               CENTRAL PENINSULA GENERAL HOSPITAL    AK Not Available          11.6           9.8
108                 PROVIDENCE VALDEZ MEDICAL CENTER    AK Not Available Not Available Not Available
109                       PROVIDENCE SEWARD HOSPITAL    AK Not Available Not Available Not Available
112                 CORDOVA COMMUNITY MEDICAL CENTER    AK Not Available Not Available Not Available
```

I am trying to bring-out the hospitals which has less HeartAttack Rate across the list.

so when I write a function to work on the first element of this list and call

```
  test <- function(x){
    if(x[[1]][,3] == min(x[[1]][,3]))
      return(head(x[[1]][1],1))

  }

test(statedata)
```

it seems to work fine but with the  below warning

```
(Warning message:
In if (x[[1]][, 3] == min(x[[1]][, 3])) return(head(x[[1]][1], 1)) :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used)

                       Hospital.Name
99 PROVIDENCE ALASKA MEDICAL CENTER
```

But when I try to use the same function code inside a lapply to loop through the  entire list element it does not seem to work and fails with the below issue

```
result <- lapply(statedata,function(statedata) if(statedata[[1]][,3] == min(statedata[[1]][,3])) return(head(statedata[[1]][1],1)) )

Error in statedata[[1]][, 3] : incorrect number of dimensions
```

Not sure if I am missing something with the lapply??

Answer (score 0):

That's right because you're masking the global variable statedata with the function parameter statedata. A better way would be:

```
statedata = lapply(statedata, function(s) {
 s[!is.na(as.integer(s$HeartAttack)),,drop=F]
})
wm = which.min(sapply(statedata, function(s) min(s$HeartAttack)))
wState = statedata[[wm]]
wState[which.min(wState$HeartAttack), "Hospital"]
```

The first lapply is to remove the "Not Available" hospitals, the next sapply is to find the worst state, and then the worst state is used to grab the worst hospital in the worst state.